# a game of quidditch using conditional probabilities

Tags: self-study, bayesian, conditional-probability

The Snitch in the game of Quidditch is famously elusive. It is hidden in one of n boxes, location uncertain, and, for k = 1, . . . , n, is in box k with probability $p_k$. If it is in box k, a search of the box will only reveal it with probability $α_k$. Now suppose a search of box i has been conducted and the Snitch has not been found. (a) What is the conditional probability that the Snitch is actually in box i? (b) You move on to a new box j (but have not yet searched it). What is the conditional probability that it is in box j?

I would like to know how to do part b. I know I need to use the Baye's theorem but would like a clear explanation on how to apply it.

Comment: Have you tried using Bayes to calculate $P(\text{Snitch in box i} | \text{snitch not observed in box i})$?

Comment: I edited two cases in which you wrote notation for multiplication but I think you meant to use a subscript. If I'm mistaken, revert the changes.